# How do I install Bidet on Toilet that does not have tank

Tags: toilet

I live in an apartment building that was built in the late 60's.

I wish to install Bidet .

However, all instructions show how to install Bidet on toilet with tank.

Toilets in our building (well, in my apartment at least) don't have tank, but pipes from toilet go to wall.

How-to video in [this Amazon product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009ZLRSJ6) shows toilet with tank

Can you guide me.

Comment: Not without knowing something about your plumbing. Please revise your post to include photos and/or a detailed description of the valves and lines involved.

Comment: @isherwood I would imagine something like this https://www.rotorooter.com/plumbing-basics/frequently-asked-questions/bathroom-plumbing/can-i-install-a-commercial-toilet-in-my-home/

Comment: I can guess, too. I'd rather not.